# php.ini - session_save_path not working on all pages

Tags: php, linux, session

I have a php.ini file in the root folder with the following:

**php.ini**

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
session.save_path = "/home/user/public_html/_tmp"
```

I have a header file which checks the count of a particular session variable as below:

**header.php**

```
session_start();
if (count($_SESSION['b']) == 0) {
    $item_count = 0;
}
else {
    foreach ($_SESSION['b'] as $unique => $item) {
        $item_count += $item['qty'];
    }
}
```

**homepage.php**

```
<?php
    include 'structure/header.php';
    echo $item_count;
?>
```

The count always shows as 0 on the homepage but any of my other pages that are not placed in the `public_html` folder (i.s `http://www.website.com/pages/xxx.php` show correct and if I move `homepage.php` into a folder it works fine too. So when the session count should be say 2 i get:

```
http://www.website.com/homepage.php = 0 = INCORRECT
http://www.website.com/pages/anotherpage.php = 2 = CORRECT
http://www.website.com/pages/homepage.php = 2 = CORRECT
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: have you tried var_dumping in each page to see what $_session equals?

Answer (score -1):

In your php pages

put ob_start();  at the begining of all pages that is before session_start() line

and try again